# Android: onConfigurationChanged() is not calling on change in Orientation

Tags: android

I have a activity in which when i change the orientation then `onConfigurationChanged()` is not called.

Please help me to sort out this issue. I tried but could not find the reason for this.

**Code:**

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration configure){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(configure);
    setLayout(); //Set the layout.

    //Get the orientation of the device and set the gravity according to that.
    if(configure.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        parentLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    } else if(configure.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        parentLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    }
}

<activity android:name=".AddProductsActivity" 
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Comment: Use a real device, emulator doesn't support.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are targeting `API 13` or higher, you have to add `screenSize`.Please change this line:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

to

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

Comment: Yes, if you are targetting API 13 or higher, you have to add `screenSize`.